# React Native Navigation Sidebar and TabBar toggled navigation

Tags: react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I want to toggle between sidebar and tab navigation. I have it so that it currently switches between tabs and sidebar depending on the screen size, however since they are separate navigators it resets the navigation stack. Is there any way to persist the navigation stack when I change navigators?

If there is a way to have a Drawer and TabBar navigator with the same screens at the same time that would also solve my problem.

```js
  <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
      mode="modal"
      initialRouteName="WalkthroughScreen"
    >
      {deviceSize(layout.width) > 0 ||
      (layout.width < 50 && Platform.OS === 'web') ? (
        <Stack.Screen name="Root" component={DrawerNavigator} />
      ) : (
        <Stack.Screen name="Root" component={BottomTabNavigator} />
      )}
```

Comment: Did you find anything that fit your needs? I'm looking for something similar. Depending if we are in desktop mode, show the Drawer Navigator, if mobile mode then show the bottom tab navigator.

Comment: @EstebanChornet see the answer I just posted, and let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was just using bottom navigation for the mobile app and drawer navigation for web and mobile web. So my code looks like this:

```js
      {Platform.OS === 'web' ? (
        <Stack.Screen name="Root" component={DrawerNavigator} />
      ) : (
        <Stack.Screen name="Root" component={BottomTabNavigator} />
      )}
```

The reason this works and not the other way is there is since it just uses platform there is never a reason for the navigator to switch mid process. So I decided to give up on tabs and use a hamburger menu for mobile web with the side drawer and a permanent side drawer on larger screens.

So in my drawer navigator `<DrawerNavigation.Navigator>` I set `drawerType` like this

```js
      drawerType={deviceSize(layout.screenWidth) === 0 ? 'front' : 'permanent'}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
FYI, I've finally decided to use `useWindowDimensions()` from react-native, and if `width >= 960px`, then show drawer navigator, otherwise bottom tab. On iPad in portrait mode will be tabs, on landscape will be drawer.

Comment: @EstebanChornet the issue with this is if someone resizes their browser the navigation will be reset and they will lose their spot